# plot line chart over stack bar chart with secondary axis using ggplot not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am just starting to use R for my chart and the chart i want to achieve is a stack bar chart with line chart that supposed to have a secondary axis. I was already able to add a secondary axis for the line.
However the line chart does't seem to follow the secondary axis but instead it uses the first one.

I would really appreciate if someone can give a pointer on what i missed.

This is how my chart look like.

[image]

My Data look like this:

```
date       Combine_Shift    Shift_Type    Prod
2018-04-02    536            PM_Shift     1088
2018-04-02    563            AM_Shift     343
2018-04-03    665            PM_Shift     1124
2018-04-03    665            AM_Shift     444
2018-04-04    658            PM_Shift     1004
2018-04-04    658            AM_Shift     493
2018-04-05    529            PM_Shift     855
2018-04-05    529            AM_Shift     1088
2018-04-06    630            PM_Shift     959
2018-04-06    630            AM_Shift     1088
2018-04-07    926            PM_Shift     1475
2018-04-07    926            AM_Shift     716
2018-04-09    701            PM_Shift     825
2018-04-09    701            AM_Shift     595
2018-04-10    605            PM_Shift     648
2018-04-10    605            AM_Shift     581
```

This is how my code look like for the chart.

```
## Convert my table to xts
ProdDB <- xts((ProdData)[,-1,0], order.by=as.Date((ProdData)[,1], "%Y-%m-%d"))

plot_Productivity <- function(date){
  answ2<-ProdDB[date]
  answ1<-fortify(answ2)

ggplot(data=answ1) + 
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal",legend.position = "top",axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = .5),plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=11,face="bold"),axis.text = element_text(size=8)) + 
  labs(title = "Productivity", x = " ", y = " ", fill = " ")  +
  scale_fill_manual(values = ProductivityPalette) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=1,byrow=TRUE)) + theme(legend.text=element_text(size=7)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = as.numeric(as.character(Prod)) , x =Index , fill = Shift_Type), stat="identity") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = as.numeric(as.character(Combine_Shift)) , x =Index))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis= sec_axis(~./2))
}
```

Comment: try - `geom_line(aes(y = as.numeric(as.character(Combine_Shift))*2 , x =Index))`. Everything is plotted on he first axis, the second is just for show

Comment: @missuse it somehow worked.. Thank you.